# How can an image be changed when a select option is changed?

Tags: jquery

I try to change the img src when an option is selected.

[This is what I've tried](http://jsfiddle.net/MXA2K/), but but it doesn't work:

```
$('#dpt').on('change', function () {
    $('.img_dpt img').attr('src',"http://images.com/dep" + val() + ".png");
});
```

My HTML is :

```
<select id="dpt">
<option value="01">Blabla</option>
<option value="02">Blabla</option>
<option value="03">Blabla</option>
</select>
```

and when I want image display :

```
<div class="img_dpt">
  <img src="http://images.com/dep/dep01.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: val() is "for me" the value of option selected

Comment: Problem is that it shoud be `$(this).val()`. You also forgot include jQuery in you jsFiddle.

Comment: yes, i solve my problem i forget $(...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

change `val()` to `this.value` or `$(this).val()`

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
$('#dpt').on('change', function () {
    $('.img_dpt img').attr('src',"http://images.com/dep" + $(this).val() + ".png");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the value of the `select` element in context using the `this` keyword, like so:

```
$(this).val()
```

[jQuery’s this: demystified](http://remysharp.com/2007/04/12/jquerys-this-demystified/)